# R package logging, combining stop and log_error

Tags: r, logging, r-package

I am using the [logger package](https://github.com/daroczig/logger) for logging an R package. Is there any way to combine stop() and log_error() somehow halt the program from running and also write the message to console (or file)?

**Edit:**
I used `log_errors(),` however, it prints one error for stop() and the other one through the logger approach.

```
library(logger)
logger_append(appender = appender_console, index = 1)
log_threshold(INFO, index = 1)
log_errors()
stop("This is an error.")
```

Which results in:

```
ERROR [2021-03-16 22:57:20] This is an error.
Error: This is an error.
```

Comment: You could use `log_errors` to automatically call `log_error` on error messages, and you can configure where to log (eg console or file) via `log_appender`.

Comment: @daroczig, thank you so much for your response. Where should I call log_errors? During loading the package (.onLoad)? I used log_errors; however, it provides one error message for the stop and one other through the logger message.  Is there a way to only print it through the logger package? Please see the updated question.